# How do I get a custom Picklist (Multi-Select) values from the Case object back from a custom controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-field

Brand new to apex and trying to piece together code from a few blogs/articles that show how to do this, but I'm not seeing values in my `selectlist` when I load the page.

**Method**

```
public List<SelectOption> cancellationReasons { get;set; }

public List<SelectOption> getCancellationReasons() {
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult statusFieldDescription = Case.Withdrawal_Cancellation_Reason__c.getDescribe();
    System.debug(statusFieldDescription);
    cancellationReasons = new list<SelectOption>();

    for (Schema.Picklistentry picklistEntry : statusFieldDescription.getPicklistValues()) {
        cancellationReasons.add(new SelectOption(pickListEntry.getValue(),pickListEntry.getLabel()));
    }
    System.debug(cancellationReasons);
    return cancellationReasons;
}
```

**VF**

```
<apex:page controller="SubmitCaseController" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectList id="reasons" size="1" required="true">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!cancellationReasons}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the simplest way to get this picklist presented is

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" ...>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Case.Withdrawal_Cancellation_Reason__c}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

where you leave it to Visualforce to do all the hard work.

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code assuming `Withdrawal_Cancellation_Reason__c` is a picklist field - perhaps someone else will. Note that you do not need the `cancellationReasons` field here and instead should make that variable a local variable within your method; your get method exposes the data in the same way to Visualforce (and avoids the cost of including that data in the page's view state).

Comment: Thanks @Keith C, can you confirm this should work for a multi-select picklist?

Wish I could use the standard controller/extension, but I am working with preexisting code in the org which I have to make use of. Hopefully that note will help other folks coming this route.

Comment: @TheEks I'm not too clear what your constraint is from the preexsiting code. You can use `apex:inputField` from a custom controller too: you just need an instance of the SObject. But perhaps you need to create something quite different from what that tag emits.

Answer (score 0):

here it is my example.

Case object, Product__c custom picklist field.

Apex Page:

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="PicklistSelectOptionController">

<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="CUSTOM PICKLIST" collapsible="false">
            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedPicklistValue}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!picklistValues}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Apex Controller:

```
public with sharing class PicklistSelectOptionController {

public String selectedPicklistValue { get; set; }
public List<SelectOption> picklistValues { get; set; }

public PicklistSelectOptionController() {
    picklistValues = new List<SelectOption>();

    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = Case.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    Schema.SObjectField F = fieldsMap.get(Case.Product__c.getDescribe().getName());
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult R = F.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> values =  R.getPicklistValues();

    for (Schema.PicklistEntry aValue : values) {
        if (aValue.isActive()) {
            picklistValues.add(new SelectOption(aValue.getValue(), aValue.getLabel()));
        }
    }
}
```

}